# Exist actually clip path for DOM?

Tags: javascript

Exist actually an method `clipPath` for DOM ? instead of use

`setAttribute("style","clip-path: value")` ?,

because i think that use setAttribute is worse for the performance, and use and method like `element.style.clipPath` will be easier.

```js
function s() {
 var i = 100, p = document.getElementById("p");
 function f(){
 if(i > 0) {
 i-= 1; 
 p.setAttribute("style","clip-path:inset(0 0 0 "+i+"%");  
 setTimeout(f, 50);
 }
 }
 f();
}
s();
```

```html
<img width="150" height="150" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/CE5lz.png" id="p">
```

Comment: So did you try `element.style.clipPath` ?

Comment: that doesnt exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to work fine when you set it. Make sure you are not including the semicolon.

```js
var x = 0, dir = 1
function move() {
  x+=dir
  if (x>=400 || x<=0) dir*=-1
  document.querySelector(".circleClass").style.clipPath = "circle(200px at " + x + "px " + x + "px)";
  window.setTimeout(move,10)
}
move()
```

```css
.circleClass {
  clip-path: circle(200px at 0px 0px);
}
```

```html
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/400/sports/" class="circleClass" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `element.style.clipPath = "..."` works fine. No, it is not better for performance.